# Slow External API request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a data intensive application on AngularJS. I noticed that the page takes about 10 seconds to load as it pulls data from the external API.

So far I have tried using angular-cache to cache the data. I'm looking into exploring web workers to preemptively pull the data in the background first but I do not know how difficult that will need. I am intending to use ng-webworkers. With that, are there any other possible solutions I can try to hasten the loading?

Comment: Nothing you do clientside will improve the network/processing speed of the external api. This is outside of your control unless you're willing to build your own api that preemptively pulls data from the external api and stores it for your app to use.

Comment: A friend suggested building a webserver to mirror over the external API but that seems like a lot of redundant work. Is there any sort of ready made open source application that can achieve this?

Comment: depends... how realtime does the data need to be? If you need up to the minute data, then you won't gain a whole lot.

Comment: Not so much on real time. Some of the data gets updated about every 15 minutes, and some updated hourly.

Comment: then any common caching solution would work.

Comment: Server side caching? In the sense I have to great a backend server to cache for my own use?

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, it's impossible to answer, but here's a few tips.

If your server API request is slow, there's not much you can do in your client application to fix that.  Look at fixing that instead.

Caching could help your second load, but not your initial load.

Web workers are more for client CPU bound operations, you're probably just waiting for the server to respond.  So I doubt it would help.

If you're making a lot of different calls, are you making them all at once, or spreading them out?  Depending on your architecture, there probably is an ideal number of simultaneous requests.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have control over the API. Can I use Web Workers to preemptively pull data?

Comment: "preemptively"? try a redis cache or something

Comment: You don't need web workers to preemptively pull data.  Web requests are asynchronous.  If you know you'll need data before it's display, feel free to request it.